# admin grid not working

Tags: magento2, grid, data-provider, di.xml

**listing file**

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">faq_listing.faq_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<settings>
    <spinner>faq_listing_columns</spinner>
    <deps>
        <dep>faq_listing.faq_listing_data_source</dep>
    </deps>
</settings>
<dataSource name="faq_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
    <settings>
        <storageConfig>
            <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">faq_id</param>
        </storageConfig>
        <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
    </settings>
    <dataProvider class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider" name="faq_listing_data_source">
        <settings>
            <requestFieldName>faq_id</requestFieldName>
            <primaryFieldName>faq_id</primaryFieldName>
        </settings>
    </dataProvider>
</dataSource>
<columns name="customer_online_columns">
    <column name="customer_id">
        <settings>
            <filter>textRange</filter>
            <label translate="true">ID</label>
            <sorting>asc</sorting>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="title">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">title</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
</columns>
```

**/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="faq_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Faq\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<virtualType name="Magento\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Faq\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
```

This error are comes to my screen so how to resolve this error ?

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver()
>   must be of the type array, null given, called in
>   /var/www/html/magento_2_2_4/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php
>   on line 206 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/magento_2_2_4/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:172
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/magento_2_2_4/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(206):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->argumentsResolver('faq_listing',
>   NULL) #1
>   /var/www/html/magento_2_2_4/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(135):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('faq_listing',
>   NULL, Array) #2
>   /var/www/html/magento_2_2_4/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(97): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure),
>   'faq_listing', Array, Object(Magento\Framew in
>   /var/www/html/magento_2_2_4/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php
>   on line 172

Answer (score 1):

> **Your column name customer_online_columns is miss-match. Please check below code is updated and working**

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">faq_listing.faq_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">faq_listing.faq_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">faq_listing_columns</item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="faq_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">faq_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">faq_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">faq_id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<columns name="faq_listing_columns">
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">faq_id</item>
               <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
               <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
   </selectionsColumn>
   <column name="customer_id">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">number</item>
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
               <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
   </column>
    <column name="title">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">title</item>
               <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

Comment: Just responding with a different bit of code and no explanation is not a good way to answer questions. Explain what column mismatch means. Winmerging the two definitions makes your answer no clearer.

Comment: @AdamLavery I updated my answer and for the next post, I will take care of it.

Comment: HI @msquare, thanks for updating but for further clarity customer_online_columns is a mismatch with what directive - spinnner? These UI components are overly complicated and docs/useful examples are lacking so trying to work out how to work them is not easy! One day there'll be an "ah" moment but not there yet!

Answer (score 0):

Check the parent and child class constructors, child class constructor may not be passing all the required arguments to will calling the parent constructor. 
After making the constructor arguments same run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` from CLI